# How to use Chromium tabs UI in a cross platform application?

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, chromium

Is there a way of using Chromium tabbed UI to develop cross platform apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium being an open source project you can use the code that does the tabs. You should browse chromium's source at http://www.chromium.org/. If you are developing on OSX with Cocoa, Rasmus Andersson has made a

> Cocoa framework for building applications that works like Chromium's window system.

You can find the framework at https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs.